# Image and video processing in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, digital-communications, video-processing

I have been working on Digital signal processing since Feb-2013. I have good command over it. Now I want to expand work in field of IMAGE and Video processing. Please suggest me best practical guide books, blogs, online links and other supporting matters related to IMAGE and Video processing .

Answer (score 2):

The following two books by by *Gonzalez and Woods* can help you with image processing

1. [Digital Image Processing Using MATLAB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130085197)
2. [Digital Image Processing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013168728X)